# Google calendar event created in wrong date and time

Tags: java, json, google-calendar-api

I am creating a Google calendar event using the following parameters.

```
{"summary":"A Contacter : BASDEO Manish (+2304279766 +23059402386) - BASDEO Manish (+33)","start":{"dateTime":"2015-03-19T00:01:00+0400"},"end":{"dateTime":"2015-03-19T00:01:00+0400"},"description":"","location":"Darwin Ave  "}
```

Howerver, Google Calendar is not taking the stating date and final date correctly.[image]

When I an creating an event from 2015-03-19T00:01:00+0400 to 2015-03-19T00:01:00+0400, why is the event created on 2015-03-18 at 9:01 pm?

Is there any way I can solve this issue ?

Regards

Comment: I think its problem with your datatime representation. When I gave 2015-03-20T00:01:00-0800, then event was created on 20th at 1:00 am. I think the offset value you gave was wrong. Check this link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339 examples and also http://www.timebie.com/std/gmt.php?q=16

Comment: I found the answer. In facts my googlecalender's timezone was wrongly set. I manually changed it to my default timezone and it worked.